# Cross Domain Scripting Enabling

Tags: tomcat, servlets, cross-domain, servlet-filters

I'm working with Tomcat and I am having some problems with Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

To my understanding, I can modify my web service's web.xml file to open the service up to the world. (Not sure how to do this for sure, but I don't want to anyway.)

How do I add a filter to allow specific websites to interact with it? eg my1.website.com, my2.website.com, and of course it's self.

The area of web.xml I believe should be modified is this...

```
<servlet>
    <description>My Description</description>
    <display-name>My Service's Display Name</display-name>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet's Name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>My Servlet's Class</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My Servlet's Name</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyPattern</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do I use something like CORS and add...

```
<servlet>
    .
    .
    .
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>my1.website.com</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>my2.website.com</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</servlet>
```

Also, is it possible to do something like...

```
<url-pattern>*.website.com</url-pattern>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to go through the server owners since they have many filters already running and I don't want to interfere with the others.

However, others interested in doing this I finally found some nice documentation mainly...

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-configuration.html

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/files/cors/web.xml.txt